# How can I convert 2 MySQL queries in 1 with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have these two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=1
UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd" WHERE id=1
```

and I would like to know how I could convert them as one with PHP

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE table_a SET column_a='abcd' WHERE id = ( 
   SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE id=1
);
```

In this case the subquery is not needed because well `id` is both coming from table_a.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. I see two possibilities:

### Simply execute queries

If you want to execute queries with no variable part, you may want to use PHP as so:

```
$pdo->exec(
    'SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=1;
    UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd" WHERE id=1'
);
```

As in:

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    if (!$pdo->exec('SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=1; UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd" WHERE id=1')) {
        echo 'Error with the queries'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Queries success'.PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

By spliting queries with a `;` you are allowed to run them one after the other

### Nested queries

Otherwise, if you are trying to retrieve the `id` in the `UPDATE` query, you could do a nested query:

```
$pdo->exec(
    'UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd"
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM table_a
        WHERE id=1
    )'
);
```

As in:

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    if (
        !$pdo->exec(
            'UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd"
            WHERE id = (
                SELECT id
                FROM table_a
                WHERE id=1
            )'
        )
    ) {
        echo 'Error with the queries'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Queries success'.PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Assumptions

I assume you know how to use `PDO`, or a **MySQL driver**, to make these queries with PHP. Otherwise, I suggest you to learn how it works with PHP and to be careful not to use `mysql` driver (which is **deprecated** in PHP 7) but to prefer `PDO` or `mysqli` drivers

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Firstly select all the columns from table and then update :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_a where id=1';
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$count = count($qry);

if ($count > 1) {
    $id = $qry["id"];

    // update query
    $updatesql = 'UPDATE table_a SET column_a="abcd" WHERE id=$id';
    $updateqry = mysql_query($updatesql);

 if ($updateqry) {
        echo "updated";
    } else {
        echo "Something error occured while connecting with database";
    }
} else {
    echo "No record Found";
}
```

Comment: I don't see `$updatesql` being executed; moreover, this could be improved thanks to nested queries